# What happens when you call Box::pin on !Unpin type?

Tags: rust

The implementation is very easy:

```
pub fn pin(x: T) -> Pin<Box<T>> {
    (box x).into()
}
```

But I wonder what actually happens if `T` is `!Unpin` (it has self reference etc) ?

How does `box x` fix up those self references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't.

An important realization about `Unpin` is that **even for `!Unpin` types, as long as you haven't pinned them, you can move them freely**.

In this case, we know the value has not been pinned, because it was moved to us as a parameter (and this is forbidden for pinned `!Unpin` types). So we can move it freely, until we create the `Pin`.

This rule make sense if we think about e.g. futures: before the future started executing (and thus was not yet pinned), it cannot have self-references because the code that is responsible to create them is inside the future, so it is yet to be run.

Comment: when to pass pinned future, and when not?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie You need to pin it before it starts executing (if it is `!Unpin`).

Comment: Also, I didn't know that for futures self-references are created only when called, not at the point the closure is created (e.g. `async block`), do you have any links about this?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie There's no need for link. Just think: a self-referential future is something like `async { let v = 0; let r = &v; foo().await; r; }`. Try to translate that into a state machine. Before the future starts executing, we only save space for it but the data, including the reference, is not there yet.

Comment: What about those captured references? They have nothing to do with self references?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie Which captured references?

Comment: Captured references inside `async {}`

Comment: @mathematicanewbie They cannot be self-referencing to the future.

Comment: What if one day, another type(not future ofc) contains self references before pinned?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie Well this will not happen, because it'll break existing code. I mean, you can do that (just like you can create self referential types without `Pin` at all), but this is unsound.